# Skype audio input - Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: 16.04, skype

I have run into a problem that I have seen a lot round here. I have Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit installed and I trying to get Skype to work.

It installed without hassle, but when calling anyone I can hear them clearly, but they cannot hear me. I tried doing a skype call test so I could hear for myself and it seems that every time I spoke during the recording it makes a buzzing noise.

The first things I tried were checking the Audio settings, turned off the option "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels" and then turned the volume all the way up for my microphone. I even went into alsa mixer and turned it up in there too.

I have tried disabling Autospawn and still had no luck.

I tried doing a sound recording and I was able to hear myself on that without any problem.

After a bit I created a new partition on my hard drive and decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit and straight out the box Skype worked.